# Finding x and y such that x^y = y^x

Tags: math

How do I find values of x and y where x to the power of y = y to the power of x.  I looked on https://www.quora.com/If-x-y-y-x-what-are-x-and-y.
It seems to miss 2 and 4.
Mathematically, how do I complete the graph and find the values?

Case 1: “x” and “y” are different.

Let's first take the natural logarithm (ln) of both sides of the equation:

ln(x^y) = ln(y^x)

Using the property of logarithms (ln(a^b) = b * ln(a)), we can simplify the equation further:

⇒ y * ln(x) = x * ln(y)

⇒ ln(x)/x = ln(y)/y = k (say)

If we look at them closely, we can figure out that “x” and “y” could be the values that are plugged into the function f(x) = ln(x)/x, and then “y” is obtained when the intersection of this graph is taken with the graph of y = k (some arbitrary constant)

(“x” and ”y” are the values, don't confuse them with the x and y coordinate axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming or coding question, is it?
For your "philosophical" question, you already answered not to be confused with the coordinates. In your link, they say y is approx. 0,3 which is a also very confusing, because it's a (bad) approximation of ln(2)/2 and ln(4)/4. If fact, it's just an example. There are an infinite couple of corresponding values before and after e (2.71... euler contant) which is the abscissa of the point at the maximum, that verify your equation. You can see that x = 2 and x = 4 are corresponding (the points on the curve have the same ordinate)
The geogebra sketch shows a cursor which should move...
Also, here is a better view of the phenomenum.
[image]

Comment: By looking at that curve it's easy to prove that 2^4 = 4^2 is actually the only integer solution.

Comment: @stef if you argue correctly, it is mathematically easy indeed. Personally, I find interesting that non integers solutions also exist. One's mind has to extend the notion of iterative product (x^n, n: integer) to x^a (a: real). Such a "quantum shift" is often the case in maths (the concept of derivative for instance). On the other hand, if the OP had gone code-wise, we would be probably talking about dichotomy or any method to find approx values of the equation's solution.